# Why does my loop stop when column has NaN values?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, regression

I'm a iterating through two unique lists and running a OLS regression model for each product/customer combination. If the first two iterations has data it will run but once it reaches an iteration that has most or all nan values the loop stops and only gives me the results from the previous iterations. How do I get my loop to continue through to the next product/customer iteration if the previous one was empty?

thanks!

```
       # Create Try and Except Clause:
    try:
        # Create empty formula list:
        formula_list = []
        # Create Empty Model List:
        model_list = []
        # Create Empty Data Frame:
        dataframe_final = pd.DataFrame()
        for g in geo_list:
            # Create Second Loop:
            for p in product_list:
                # Create Fitler DataFrame based on customer and product:
                df_filter = df[(df.Geography == g) & (df.Product == p)]
                # continue through function if dataframe is empty for a specific customer/product iteration:
                if df_filter.empty:
                   continue

                # Create a list of the numeric data types to log transform and transform dataframe:
                numerics = ["int16", "int32", "int64", "float16", "float32", "float64"]
                # Loop through the columns in the dataframe and take the log of any column that has any of the above stated data types:
                for c in [
                    c for c in df_filter.columns if df_filter[c].dtype in numerics
                ]:
                    df_filter[c] = np.log10(df_filter[c])
                    # Execute rename_function to get suffix "_Log" on desired columns:
                df_filter = rename_function(keep_same, df_filter)
                PED_Type(ped_type, df_filter)
                #df_filter = df_filter.fillna(0)
                # Create Model Formula:
                models = sm.OLS.from_formula(formula=formulas, data=df_filter).fit()
                # Append the models to the empty model_list:
                model_list.append(models)
```

Comment: `df_filter` is never null (np.Nan) or the like since it is a DataFrame. `if pd.notnull(pd.DataFrame())` throws an error.

Comment: @QuangHoang yeah that was something I just added and forgot to take out. I just made the edit on the code block and I still run into the same problem. Once it hits a product/customer combo that is empty, it stops looping.

Comment: There are just too many functions that can raise error here. Since you already have `try`, catch the error and print it out. I'd close this question for being too broad.